# SVN Finding files in any of changesets

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Let's assume in the first changeset I have two files modified

```
a.cs 
b.cs
```

In the second changeset I have just one file modified

```
a.cs
```

I'd like to use TortoiseSVN or the console to get the files in common between the two changeset. Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "intersection"?

Comment: describe your **business-task** in *common terms and conditions*, not in cryptic samples

Comment: @LazyBadger: can you point exactly one point that is cryptic? And also which word is not specific to the SVN world?

Comment: @LazyBadger: changeset = https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564458/196210

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible. The [SVNbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html) says:

> Changelist Limitations
>
> Subversion's changelist feature is a handy tool for grouping working
>   copy files, but it does have a few limitations. Changelists are
>   artifacts of a particular working copy, which means that changelist
>   assignments cannot be propagated to the repository or otherwise shared
>   with other users. Changelists can be assigned only to files—Subversion
>   doesn't currently support the use of changelists with directories.
>   Finally, you can have at most one changelist assignment on a given
>   working copy file. Here is where the blog post category and photo
>   service tag analogies break down—**if you find yourself needing to
>   assign a file to multiple changelists, you're out of luck**.

Comment: @Revious: I thought you mean changelist=changeset. In this case my answer is not an answer to your question.